# How can I pass HTML content to a Partial View in MVC-Razor like a "for" block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I'm using Chromatron theme for an admin panel in my application. There is a sidebar gadget that has HTML content and with a little CSS trick it can be shown completely different.

```
<section class="sidebar nested">
    <h2>Nested Section</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetur adipiscing elit. Maec enas id augue ac metu aliquam.</p>
    <p>Sed pharetra placerat est suscipit sagittis. Phasellus <a href="#">aliquam</a> males uada blandit. Donec adipiscing sem erat.</p>
</section>
```

I want to have a Partial View that is used like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Path/To/Partial/View"){
    <h2>Nested Section</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetur adipiscing elit. Maec enas id augue ac metu aliquam.</p>
    <p>Sed pharetra placerat est suscipit sagittis. Phasellus <a href="#">aliquam</a> males uada blandit. Donec adipiscing sem erat.</p>
}
```

TBH, I want to have functionality like I have in a `@for(...){ }` block.
Is this possible in Razor?

Comment: I don't know if it's what you want, but take a look: http://lostechies.com/hugobonacci/2011/07/11/templates-with-razor/

Comment: Thank you Felipe. but this is not what I'm looking for, or perhaps I can't get it to work. I need the same functionality as `for` blocks. I want to have a trailing block where I can insert other `@` razor directives or HTML content; exactly like a `for` block...

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing; see my [*very similar* SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21760850/173497). The closest thing I've found is the post @FelipeOriani mentioned. An `HtmlHelper` extension method works too, but I haven't figured out to store the HTML it uses as a view or partial view. But, really, I just had to give up the bracket block syntax for the helper function syntax.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was having the same dilemma. Try creating a viewmodel type with a Func property and then pass the html as  delegate.

```
public class ContainerViewModel
{
    public String Caption { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Width { get; set; }
    public Func<object, IHtmlString> Content { get; set; }
}

@Html.Partial("Container", new ContainerViewModel()
{
    Name = "test",
    Caption = "Test container",
    Content =  
    @<text>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </text>,
    Width = 600
})
```

You can call it like this in your partial.

```
@Model.Content(null)
```

If you want to be fancy you can add this extension method.

```
public static class PartialExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Display<T>
        (this T model, Expression<Func<T, Func<Object, IHtmlString>>> content) 
    {
        var compiled = content.Compile();
        return compiled.Invoke(model).Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

Then, any time you use this pattern, you can call it like this in your partial (not fully tested).

```
@model ContainerViewModel
@Model.Display(m => m.Content)  // Use delegate property
```

Hope this works for you.

It works because the @... syntax creates a little HtmlHelper for you that consumes a Model (which you're declaring here as type `object`, and passing `null` for), and returns an `IHtmlString`.

BEWARE form values don't seem to post to the server if @Html.BeginForm is used in the content.

Therefore, wrap your form around the container.

Comment: I love this solution but the <dynamic, ... felt really dirty, so I did some poking. It turns out you're creating an implicit little HtmlHelper that takes a Model, so the type of the input arg to the Func is anything you like (object if you want), and the return type is always IHtmlString. Edited answer to reflect this. Works perfectly!

Comment: This solution is absolutely brilliant! I can create my widgets/partials with surrounding HTML content and inject the content inside it using this method. It's clean and works really well! Thank you!

Comment: excellent solution where nothing works for child action this works perfectly as parameter, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want some sort of htmlhelper function to generate that content. Have you looked into implementing it as a helper instead of a partial view?

Comment: I've looked into "Inline Helpers" and it does the job; there actually are a few ways to pass content to a place holder; but I think my HTML code will look much cleaner if I could use a notation like what i've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

For aspnet core razor take a look at "Templated Razor delegates" [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#templated-razor-delegates)

With those you can create razor templates using the syntax:

```
Func<T, object> template = @<div>@item.Foo</div>;
```

(where T is your type).

You can then pass that function around (in to partial views for example) and invoke as such:

```
@template(new T { Foo = "Bar" })
```

Notice that the parameter passed in is accessed via `@item`. (My VS adds a red squiggle for this but it can be ignored!)

If you don't want a strongly typed template, just change T to dynamic.