# Define something like for in ASP.NET MVC 3 to pass real html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can define a custom block like `@for` in Razor view? I read about `@helper` [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) and [here](http://lostechies.com/hugobonacci/2011/07/11/templates-with-razor/) also there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588695/how-can-i-pass-html-content-to-a-partial-view-in-mvc-razor-like-a-for-block) but `@helper` method just define html tags at first then when you want to use in views just can pass some parameters, in other hand `@for` block is that I want, in views you can pass Html (with intelligence support), Does any one have any idea about this? I also think about modify razor source code! (if possible) Is there any better way?

Comment: argh - want to follow the question here but am struggling. can you elaborate a little on the required use case plz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [Razor Templated Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx).