# ASP.NET MVC3 HtmlHelper extension method like BeginForm that uses a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I created an extension method based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8292524/173497) to the SO question [c# - How can I create a Html Helper like Html.BeginForm - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292497/how-can-i-create-a-html-helper-like-html-beginform) and it works fine.

Can I move the embedded HTML in the extension method into a partial view and use that partial view in the method while preserving it's current behavior? In particular, I want to be able to 'wrap' a block of arbitrary HTML.

I ask not out of any pressing need, but simply out of a desire to maintain HTML consistently, e.g. as views and partial views. I imagine it will be a lot easier to spot any problems with the HTML if it's in a view or partial view too.

Here's the `HtmlHelper` extension method:

```
public static IDisposable HelpTextMessage(this HtmlHelper helper, bool isHidden, string heading)
{
    TextWriter writer = helper.ViewContext.Writer;

    writer.WriteLine(
        String.Format(
            "<div class=\"help-text {0}\">",
            isHidden ? "help-text-hidden" : ""));

    writer.WriteLine(
        String.Format(
            "<div class=\"help-text-heading\">{0}</div>",
            heading));

    writer.Write("<div class=\"help-text-body\">");

    return new HelpTextMessageContainer(writer);
}
```

Here's the `HelpTextMessageContainer` class:

```
private class HelpTextMessageContainer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TextWriter _writer;

    public HelpTextMessageContainer(TextWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _writer.Write("</div></div>");
    }
}
```

In a view, I can use the extension method like this:

```
@using(Html.HelpTextMessage(Model.HelpText.IsHelpTextHidden(Model.SomeHelpMessage), "Something"))
{
    @:To do something, first do something-more-specific, then do another-something-more-specific.
}
```

Or I could use it like this too:

```
@using(Html.HelpTextMessage(Model.HelpText.IsHelpTextHidden(Model.SomeHelpMessage), "Something"))
{
    <p>To do something, first do something-more-specific, then do another-something-more-specific.</p>
    <p>Also, keep in mind that you might need to do something-else-entirely if blah-blah-blah.</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any way to move the "embedded HTML" into a partial view exactly, but a slightly more-friendly way to encapsulate the HTML in a way that provides HTML and Razor syntax highlighting and Intellisense is to move into a view helper function in a file under the app *App_Code* folder as described in [this post on "Hugo Bonacci's Blog"](http://lostechies.com/hugobonacci/2011/07/11/templates-with-razor/).

Here's my helper function:

```
@helper HelpTextMessage(bool isHidden, string heading, Func<object, object> content)
{
    <div class="help-text @(isHidden ? "help-text-hidden" : "")">
        <div class="help-text-heading">
            @heading
        </div>
        <div class="help-text-body">
            @content(null)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Assuming the above helper function is in a file named *ViewHelpers.cshtml* in the *App_Code* folder, it can be called in a view like this:

```
@ViewHelpers.HelpTextMessage(false, "Something",
    @:To do something, first do something-more-specific, then do another-something-more-specific.
)
```

or this:

```
@ViewHelpers.HelpTextMessage(false, "Something",
    <p>To do something, first do something-more-specific, then do another-something-more-specific.</p>
    <p>Also, keep in mind that you might need to do something-else-entirely if blah-blah-blah.</p>
)
```

I like having the embedded HTML in a view more than I do being able to use the `@using(Html.HelpTextMessage(...){ ... }` syntax, so I'm pretty happy with this as a solution.